# How to know if my flutter web app is running on mobile or desktop

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

How do I know if my web flutter application is running on desktop or on mobile ?
I can't use kIsWeb because it says if the app is built for the web not if it's running on the web.
Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

In order to detect if Flutter Web is running on a Mobile device (iOS or Android only), you can detect that in two steps:

- Use `kIsWeb` to detect whether you're on web or not
- Use `defaultTargetPlatform` to get the default platform (it'll give you the operating system)*

Here's a test that I just did calling `defaultTargetPlatform` from Safari on iOS:

[image]

To use `defaultTargetPlatform`, you need to import the following:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
```

Example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

final isWebMobile = kIsWeb &&
    (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS ||
        defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android);
```

- `defaultTargetPlatform` is already web-aware and does the navigator shenanigans for you. You can see the implementation here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/_platform_web.dart

Answer (score -4):

Maybe you could make a desicion based on the screensize.

```
var screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
final double width = screenSize.width;
final double height = screenSize.height - kToolbarHeight;
```

If height or width is below a defined value, you could estimate that the app is executed on a mobile device.